# is there any way to play sound using qpython?

Tags: python, qpython

I'm trying to run the following script in qpython. Can you please suggest an alternative for mpg321 in android?

```
import os
from time import sleep as sleep

pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(pwd)

work_time = int(raw_input("give the working time. Default time is 25 minutes : ") or "25")
chill_time = int(raw_input("give the chill out time. Default time is 3 minutes : ") or "3")
total_time = int(raw_input("give the total working time. Default is 3 hours : ") or "3")*60

loop_count = (total_time/(work_time+chill_time+1))+1



def notificationsystem(work_time, chill_time):
    print "stop procrastinating and start working"
    os.system('mpg321 start.mp3 &')
    sleep(work_time*60)
    print ("take a break for %s minutes" % chill_time)
    os.system('mpg321 stop.mp3 &')
    sleep(chill_time*60)


while loop_count > 0:
    notificationsystem(work_time, chill_time)
    loop_count -= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an android device you can import
`androidhelper` and use `mediaPlay("start.mp3")`...

Or better convert your console app to a gui app using kivy
and use `kivy.core.audio.SoundLoader("start.mp3")`...

kivy is worth learning it... it works on desktops and androids

Answer (score 2):

You can try the builtin sl4a module:

```
import sl4a
ad = sl4a.Android()
ad.mediaPlay("/your/path/to/sound.mp3")
```

Comment: when I tried import sl4a, it says the module can't be found. I also tried to install the sl4a by using pip.main(['install','sl4a']) and it didn't work. I can download few other modules like requests though. Any idea what happened to sl4a?

Comment: Instead of sl4a, you could try importing android, it does the same thing. Also, have you tried reinstalling QPython?

Comment: Yes I've tried re-installing QPython and then tried to install sl4a. It didn't work. However, 'from androidhelper import Android' worked ! Thanks. As an alternate you could suggest/ add this as an alternate in the answer also !!

Answer (score 0):

`ad.mediaPlay works!`

Now how to stop it from playing after it has started playing?

I found it!

`ad.mediaPlayClose()`

And they duration of the play can be controlled by

`ad.eventWait(4000)`